# How to use useEffect to produce html elements properly?

Tags: reactjs

I wish to produce this 3x3 square inside my dom :

```
<div className="x1x1" onClick={() => console.log("1x1")}></div>
<div className="x1x2" onClick={() => console.log("1x2")} />
<div className="x1x3" onClick={() => console.log("1x3")} />
<div className="x2x1" onClick={() => console.log("2x1")} />
<div className="x2x2" onClick={() => console.log("2x2")}></div>
<div className="x2x3" onClick={() => console.log("2x3")} />
<div className="x3x1" onClick={() => console.log("3x1")} />
<div className="x3x2" onClick={() => console.log("3x2")} />
<div className="x3x3" onClick={() => console.log("3x3")} />
```

for that I have created a simple loop

```
for (let c = 1; c < 4; c++) {
  for (let r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
    array.push(
      <div
        key={`x${c}x${r}`}
        className={`x${c}x${r}`}
        onClick={() => console.log(`${c}x${r}`)}
      ></div>
    );
  }
}
```

This piece of code works well when it is a separate function but when I put it inside `useEffect` it does not produce the elements on DOM. To reproduce you can click [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-snow-60q1x).

Comment: See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hooks-xol22?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use state in `useEffect`.
Something like this:

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
   const _array = [];
   // whatever
   setArray(_array);
}, []);
```

Check [your modified snippet here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-shadow-uf9vg?file=/src/App.js:99-490).

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try something like this :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    createDiv();
  }, []);

  function createDiv() {
    console.log("createDiv");
    let arr = [];

    for (let c = 1; c < 4; c++) {
      for (let r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
        arr.push({ c, r });
      }
    }

    console.log("arr", arr);
    setArray(arr);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {array &&
        array.map((elem, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`x${elem.c}x${elem.r}`}
            onClick={() => console.log(`${elem.c}x${elem.r}`)}
            style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px", border: "1px solid black", 
                     display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: 
                     "center", flexWrap: "wrap" }}
          >
            {`${elem.c}x${elem.r}`}
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```